# Set Multi-Select Custom Field via Pardot API

Tags: api, http, salesforce

does anyone know if (and how)it is possible to set the value of a custom field when it´s type is "Multi-Select"? I cannot find any information about it in the official Pardot API documentation.
I hope that this is possible... if not, do you know a workaround?

Thanks for your help!

I already tried to set the value of the multi-select custom field as an normal string, but it didn´t work.